# ¿Cómo reemplazar caracter extraño?

Tags: php, php7

Tengo un `input` que genera etiquetas con `javaScript tag-it` hasta aquí todo perfecto.

Al mandarlo por `post` en el `php` me retorna esto.

```
etiqueta×etiqueta2×etiqueta3 .....
```

Siempre me mete el carácter "×" no es una "x", he intentado remplazarlo con la función `php` `str_replace` pero no hay forma de cambiarlo por "," no lo reconoce.

¿Alguna idea para sustituir ese carácter tan extraño?

Comment: Para sustituirlo lo tienes que hacer como `str_replace("×", "_", $tu_string);` Esto te devolverá `etiqueta_etiqueta2_etiqueta3` Si lo que quieres es realmente separarlo en un array, te recomiendo usar `explode("×", $tu_string);` para que te devuelva `arrray([0] => etiqueta, [1] => etiqueta2, [2] => etiqueta3)`

Comment: Ahora, con tag-it realmente no tiene caso mandarte un string, cuando puedes enviártelo como array, ¿estás usando AJAX o estás usando un POST normal con un formulario?

Comment: ¿Por qué usas tag-it? ¿Qué tipo de dato quieres mandar al servidor en realidad? ¿Si lo que necesitas es una cadena separada por comas, por qué no la mandas así directamente desde el cliente?

Comment: Es un formulario normal por post, el caso esque quiero meterlo en un array pero tampoco puedo porque el caracter es raro, y la funcion str_replace y explode no hacen caso.

Comment: Pero ¿de dónde sale ese carácter? ¿Por qué se agrega a los datos que pasas? Eso es lo que debes revisar del lado del cliente (Javascript)

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo donde envias los datos al PHP?

Comment: Solucione el asunto modificando el jqueryvar removeTag = $('<a><span class="text-icon">\xd7</span></a>') // \xd7 is an X